# PDO doesn't return anything

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am having some problems with running my PDO query.
I am trying to get the number of database entries with matching criteria from a search form. The query returns nothing. $query->errorInfo() prints a HY093 error. The session variables are indeed set, I've checked, and there definitely are entries in the database that match the session values.

```
$_SESSION["searchfield"] = $_POST["searchfield"];
$_SESSION["searchtype"] = $_POST["searchtype"];

//connection comes from an included file.
$query=$connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM vendor WHERE :searchby = :searchcriteria");
$query->bindValue(":searchby", $_SESSION["searchtype"]);
$query->bindValue(":searchcriteria", $_SESSION["searchfield"]);
$query->execute();
$countid=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I just can't find anything wrong in my syntax. It works well without filtering:

```
$query=$connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM vendor");
$countid=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

@GolezTrol, seems like that may be the problem, thanks.

Comment: Does you request return something in PHP my admin?

Comment: Can you specify a field name (column name) as a parameter? I thought [that wasn't possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365357/pdo-passing-a-field-name-as-a-variable).

Comment: Ensure that you do indeed have something of equivalent value for $_SESSION['searchtype'] and $_SESSION['searchfield'] that exitst in your db

Comment: @GolezTrol No, it's not possible.

Comment: @deceze I believe Golez was being sarcastic. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$_SESSION["searchfield"] = $_POST["searchfield"];
$_SESSION["searchtype"] = $_POST["searchtype"];

//connection comes from an included file.
$query=$connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM vendor WHERE ".$_SESSION["searchtype"]." = :searchcriteria");
$query->bindValue(":searchcriteria", $_SESSION["searchfield"]);
$query->execute();
$countid=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Edit: the change is bold as somebody is asking where is the change
     $query=$connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM vendor WHERE "**.$_SESSION["searchtype"].**" = :searchcriteria");

Comment: Try _what_?? Please always include a good explanation of what you changed and why it makes a difference.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The $query->errorInfo() doesn't show any error, but there still are no result even though I am SURE that there are entries in the database that match.